# Book on the Method of Sieves

Tags: references, nonparametric, sieve-estimator

I am seeking recommendations for a good book on the method of sieves, with clear explanations of its differences to the method of kernel, its statistical properties as well as its application.

The level of the book should be suitable for a graduate math and statistics degree.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources (not all books):

**Papers:**

[Chapter 76 Large Sample Sieve Estimation of Semi-Nonparametric Models (Handbook of Econometrics)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Chapter-76-Large-Sample-Sieve-Estimation-of-Models-Chen/c3ce78766a58ece15bc2b1ee2a8d33c3b8549589)
I consider this the gold standard treatment of Sieve, it is theory heavy

[Sieve Extremum Estimation](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1057%2F978-1-349-95121-5_2695-1)
This is an easier version of the above

[Nonparametric Sieve Regression: Least Squares, Averaging Least Squares, and Cross-Validation](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/HandbookNonparametrics.html)

**Books:**

[Abstract inference by  Ulf Grenander](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471082678)  This is the founding treatment

[All of Nonparametric Statistics  by  Larry Wasserman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387251456)
Ch.8 and 10 would be helpful

[Empirical Processes in M-Estimation by  Sara A. van de Geer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521123259) This book is good for learning the techniques needed for the asymptotic analysis of sieve

[Mathematical Foundations of Infinite-Dimensional Statistical Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107043166) 
This is not about sieves but the chapter on approximation theory is very relevant to sieve

**Videos:**

[Nonparametric Sieve Estimation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqecz-DL-jI)